# Label as the same if the first part of string is the same

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Some example data:

```
    id_trial        
 001_a.txt          
 001_a_t2.txt       
 949482_b.txt       
 949482_b_t2.txt    
 95_c.txt           
 95_c_t2.txt
```

Note: strings of varying length, but length is equal for pairs minus "_t2"

How can I make it so that if the part of the string before `_t2` is the same both would labeled, in a new column, as such.
That is, I want something like:

```
    id_trial         subject
 001_a.txt           person_a
 001_a_t2.txt        person_a
 949482_b.txt        person_b
 949482_b_t2.txt     person_b
 95_c.txt            person_c
 95_c_t2.txt         person_c
```

Even this would work:

```
    id_trial         subject
 001_a.txt               a
 001_a_t2.txt            a
 949482_b.txt            b
 949482_b_t2.txt         b
 95_c.txt                c
 95_c_t2.txt             c
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `sub` to extract the prefix part

```
df1$subject <-   sub('([^_]+_.).*', '\\1',sub('([^_]+)\\1+',
          '\\1', df1$id_trial))
df1
#        id_trial  subject
#1   personn_a.txt person_a
#2 person_a_t2.txt person_a
#3    person_b.txt person_b
#4 person_b_t2.txt person_b
#5  personnn_c.txt person_c
#6 person_c_t2.txt person_c
```

If you need a `numeric` subject

```
as.numeric(factor(df1$subject))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

#### Update

For the second dataset

```
df2$subject <- sub('\\d+_([a-z]+).*', '\\1', df2$id_trial)
df2
#         id_trial subject
#1       001_a.txt       a
#2    001_a_t2.txt       a
#3    949482_b.txt       b
#4 949482_b_t2.txt       b
#5        95_c.txt       c
#6     95_c_t2.txt       c
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(id_trial = c("personn_a.txt", "person_a_t2.txt", 
"person_b.txt", "person_b_t2.txt", "personnn_c.txt", "person_c_t2.txt"
)), .Names = "id_trial", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(id_trial = c("001_a.txt", "001_a_t2.txt", 
"949482_b.txt", 
"949482_b_t2.txt", "95_c.txt", "95_c_t2.txt")), .Names = "id_trial", 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but I'm sadly still having trouble... To make the script robust, I want it to look elsewhere for the "-6L" part...something like 'paste( "-", nrow(old_df), "L", sep = "")', except, obviously, this won't work it I simply substitute it for '-6L'...any thoughts?

Comment: @InNoam I think you are mentioning about the data part in my solution.  I got it by reading the data with `read.table` and used `dput(df1)` to get the output.  It is just for reproducibility.  You don't need to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I found it hard to articulate my final problem in a comment, so I updated the question. The strings in the subject column are being 'cut off' because while pairs are of equal string length, minus the "_t2", non pairs are not. Sorry for asking so much.

Comment: @InNoam  I checked your expected result and updated the solution.  Can you check it now

Comment: @InNoam Do you have `personn` and `person` in your original dataset or is it just typo?

Comment: I am trying to show that the "person" bit can vary in length. In reality, they are subject IDs which vary in length, e.g., 001, 00248, 000338, etc.

Comment: @InNoam The pattern you are showing now is different from the one you showed earlier

Comment: Now I know I need to take the time to familiarize myself with -- clearly very useful -- regex. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @InNoam Thanks for your feedback.  Learning regex would be very useful for string manipulations